# Performance of using a nested table inside the IN clause - Oracle

Tags: performance, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to use a nested table inside the `IN` clause in a PL-SQL block.

First, I have defined a TYPE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VARCHAR_ARRAY AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767);
```

Here is my PL-SQL block using the 'BULK COLLECT INTO':

```
DECLARE
  COL1 VARCHAR2(50) := '123456789';
  N_TBL                VARCHAR_ARRAY := VARCHAR_ARRAY();
  C NUMBER;
BEGIN

    -- Print timestamp
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('START: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP  ,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss.FF'));

    SELECT    COLUMN1
      BULK COLLECT INTO N_TBL
    FROM MY_TABLE
    WHERE     COLUMN1 = COL1;


    SELECT    COUNT(COLUMN1)
      INTO C
    FROM      MY_OTHER_TABLE
    WHERE     COLUMN1 IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(N_TBL));

    -- Print timestamp
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ENDED: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP  ,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss.FF'));

END;
```

And the output is:

```
START: 01-08-2014 12:36:14.997
ENDED: 01-08-2014 12:36:17.554
```

It takes more than **2.5 seconds** (2.557 seconds exactly)

Now, If I replace the nested table by a subquery, like this:

```
DECLARE
  COL1 VARCHAR2(50) := '123456789';
  N_TBL                VARCHAR_ARRAY := VARCHAR_ARRAY();
  C NUMBER;
BEGIN

    -- Print timestamp
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('START: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP  ,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss.FF'));

    SELECT    COUNT(COLUMN1)
      INTO C
    FROM      MY_OTHER_TABLE
    WHERE     COLUMN1 IN (
                          -- Nested table replaced by a subquery
                          SELECT    COLUMN1
                          FROM MY_TABLE
                          WHERE     COLUMN1 = COL1
    );

    -- Print timestamp
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ENDED: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP  ,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss.FF'));

END;
```

The output is:

```
START: 01-08-2014 12:36:08.889
ENDED: 01-08-2014 12:36:08.903
```

It takes only **14 milliseconds**...!!!

What could I do to enhance this PL-SQL block ?
Is there any database configuration needed?

Comment: You can write this shorter as `WHERE COLUMN1 MEMBER OF N_TBL`

Comment: Thanks @Wernfried, it makes the code more readable. Anyway, the result is the same :(

Answer (score 2):

Are the two query plans different?

Assuming that they are, the difference is likely that the optimizer has reasonable estimates about the number of rows the subquery will return and, thus, is able to choose the most efficient plan.  When your data is in a nested table (I'd hate to use the word `array` in the type declaration here since that implies that you're using a `varray` when you're not), Oracle doesn't have information about how many elements are going to be in the collection.  By default, it's going to guess that the collection has as many elements as your data blocks have bytes.  So if you have 8k blocks, Oracle will guess that your collection has 8192 elements.

Assuming that your actual query doesn't return anywhere close to 8192 rows and that it actually returns many more or many fewer rows, you can potentially use the [cardinality hint](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3779680732446#15740265481549) to let the optimizer make a more accurate guess.  For example, if your query generally returns a few dozen rows, you probably want something like

```
SELECT    COUNT(COLUMN1)
  INTO C
FROM      MY_OTHER_TABLE
WHERE     COLUMN1 IN (SELECT /*+ cardinality(t 50) */ column_value 
                        FROM TABLE(N_TBL) t);
```

The literal you put in the `cardinality` hint doesn't need to be particularly accurate, just close to general reality.  If the number of rows is completely unknown the [dynamic_sampling](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF50913) hint can help.

If you are using Oracle 11g, you may also benefit from [cardinality feedback](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2010/04/something-new-i-learned-about-estimated.html) helping the optimizer learn to better estimate the number of elements in a collection.